# Question about electric potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, voltage

> Suppose I take a hollow spherical conductor with inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$. I put a charge $+q$ at the centre of the conductor (in the hollow region.) What will be the potential inside the hollow region (region where $a>r$) ($r≠0$) of the sphere. Please provide detailed answer while talking about what distance to take.

My major confusion is that I'm going to consider the potential due to charges at the surface of a and b. While doing that, what will be the potential at r (where a>r) (let's call it point x) due to the -q charge formed at the surface a. The solution tells me it should be
k(-q)/a but why so? The distance of the point a from the point x is not a. Then why is the distance considered a? Since potential is (k × charge)/ (distance between the charge and point taken into consideration)
I have similar doubt for potential due to charge +q at the surface of distance b from the centre.

I'll try to be more elaborate with exactly what's confusing me. I'm only going to talk about potential at point x due to charge distribution at surface a (surface at distance a from the centre of sphere.)
At point x, where I want to know the potential, it is a hollow region with electric field. Potential cannot be the same as on the surface a. It should increase. So, I take a look at point x and try to understand the charge distribution at surface a. I realise there is a electric field. The potential cannot be the same at point x due to surface a as on surface a itself. It should change. That's it. I'm not able to progress further. I'm unable to think what should happen next.[[Arrrows are electric field lines. I have marked what I consider poing x.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T5uq.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T5uq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you go back to basics and consider the total work done per unit test charge in bringing a test charge from infinity to $r=x$. The journey is in three stages...

For $r$ > $b$, apply Gauss's law to a spherical surface of radius $r$ centred on the  centre of the hollow metal sphere. This, bearing in mind the symmetry, gives a familiar value for the electric field strength, so you can evaluate the work done per unit charge going from $r$ =$\infty$ to $r=b$ (that is the potential at $r=b$).

For $b\geq r \geq a$ you are inside the metal, where you know the value of the field strength in electrostatic conditions, so the work integral in going from $b$ to $a$ couldn't be easier.

For $r<a$ you use Gauss's law + symmetry as before (showing that the symmetrically disposed charges on the metal are irrelevant), so you can evaluate the extra work in going from $r=b$ to $r=x$.

Answer (score 0):

For:

$r < a$:
Spherically symmetric charge distributions at larger radii don't matter, so it's the standard point charge potential.

$a\le r \le b$:
There is no electric field inside the conductor, so $\Phi(r) = \Phi(a)$.

$r \gt b$:
Given spherical symmetry: all that matters is the total charge inside the sphere of radius $r$, which doesn't depend on the presence of the neutral conductor.